# Retrieve string array from C++ in C# through DCOM

Tags: c#, c++, dcom

I have an application that needs to retrieve an array of strings from another computer. I am fairly certain that everything works on the C++ side as I have other cases doing something similar but between C++. The first example below is how I image it would but with a function call from C# (which does not work). So how do I get the *printers* to work in this case?

```
IntPtr printers;
int numPrinters;

globalPrinter.GetAllPrinterNames(out numPrinters, printers);
string[] printerNames;
MarshalUnmananagedArray2Struct(printers, numPrinters, out printerNames); //perhaps a later case to figure out
```

Inside C++:

```
STDMETHODIMP CPrinter::GetAllPrinterNames(long* pValSize, BSTR** pVal)
{
    StackLock<CPrinter> aLock(this);

    PRINTER_INFO_2*    list;
    DWORD               numPrinters = 0;
    DWORD               sz = 0;
    DWORD               Level = 2;

    EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS, NULL, Level, NULL, 0, &sz, &numPrinters);
    if (!EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS, NULL, Level, (LPBYTE)list, sz, &sz, &numPrinters))
    {
        free(list);
    }

    *pValSize = numPrinters;

    *pVal = (BSTR*) ::CoTaskMemAlloc((*pValSize) * sizeof(BSTR));

    for (int n = 0; n <= *pValSize; n++) {

        String printerName = list[n].pPrinterName;
        (*pVal)[n] = printerName.AllocBSTR(); //Help library allocs the BSTR.
    }
    free(list);

    return S_OK;
}
```

.idl:

```
[id(3), helpstring("method GetAllPrinterNames")] HRESULT GetAllPrinterNames([out] long* length, [out, size_is(, *length)] BSTR **Message);
```

Comment: If you're having trouble passing a string array, try passing a callback to the C# program, then when you get the printers in C# iterate the array of strinsg, passing each string one at a time into the callback.

Comment: I think I solved it correctly, although the answer will come tomorrow when I've got some sleep and can think more clearly.